# Word 2010 footnotes without links to the top, and without brackets

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, footnote

I have a document that has two issues:

1. I prefer the numbering format for footnotes to be **`[1]`** instead of **`1`**. I replaced `^f` with `[^&]`, but it only updated the number format for the footnote links in the main document, without adding square brackets to the numbering of the footnotes themselves (at the bottom of the page).
2. Footnotes don't link back to main document text from to which they are linked.  How can I make two-way footnote links so that footnote links take you to a footnote (as they already do), but also that the footnote itself is linked back to the document text where the footnote link is located.

###### Example Images

Clicking on a footnote link (red circle) in the main document jumps to the associated footnote at the bottom of the page:
[image: link to footnote]

Clicking on a footnote's number (red circle) doesn't jump back to the footnote link:
[image: footnote]

Comment: Thanks @BlindSpots for the reply.  I uploaded an image as an example.  This is for a file that I already have, not for a new file.

Comment: But when I make a new document and create a footnote that behavior of both linking to each other works fine,

Comment: Can Word 365 fix that file by making both numbers links to each other?

Answer (score 1):

### Word 2010 vs. Word 365

I used Word 365 for testing.  It may be that the behavior differs in Word 2010 but I suspect that you can get largely the same behavior in Word 2010, and before upgrading Word *solely* for this behavior, you should first ensure:

1. Formatting

   - If you do *anything* to restrict your "Replace" to the "Main Document" or "Footnotes"
     then "Replace All" will not be applied to both sections.  Some examples:

     - you first perform a FIND in one of those sections
     - you have *any* text selected in your document
   - Solution:

     - either, perform "Replace All" for both sections individually (toggle between "Find In" sections);
       [image]
     - or, ensure you have nothing selected before bringing up the "Replace" dialog
       **Home > Editing > Replace** or
       <sup><kbd>ALT+H</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>R</kbd></sup>
       [image]
2. Linking

   - after adding the brackets ensure you are clicking on the actual `footnote mark` when trying to return to the main text.  The links are very small, superscript, and often only one character wide.
   - If you can see both the footnote as well as the link to the footnote in the text at the same time (layout), the insertion point will move between them (linked), but you will not get the *jump* effect you may be expecting (or first got in one direction).

### Footnote Number formatting

To clarify, the method you are using is not really changing the formatting of the footnote references which Word refers to as `footnote marks`.

MS Word has no built-in ability to format a `footnote mark` to include brackets. You are using MS Word's "Find and Replace" to add square brackets around any `footnote marks` the document contains.

1. You search for all `footnote marks` using `^f` and replace them with `[^&]`
2. This effectively makes your references `[^f]`
3. In my tests it does not affect the linkability of `^f` in any way.

### Notes

1. Any added square brackets are not actually part of a `footnote mark` so it is recommended to do this find/replace only once when your document is completed.  If not, you run the risk of having redundant pairs of nested square brackets that will need to be removed.
2. You could add pre-formatted footnotes (after formatting a first batch) by copying and pasting an existing footnote link such as `[1]` in ***...all lived happily ever after* <sup>`[1]`</sup>**. Because of the one-to-one relationship between footnote links and their associated footnote, Word will auto-renumber the pasted link and create a duplicate footnote (also renumbered) without affecting the square brackets in the footnote.

If you do run into the problem of duplicated sets of square brackets, you can fix by:

1. searching for all double left brackets `[[` and replacing them with a single left bracket `[`;
2. repeating step #1 until MS Word returns **"All done. We made 0 replacements."** This ensures there are no doubles `[[` triples `[[[` quadruples `[[[[` etc.;
   [image]
3. searching for all double right brackets `]]` and replacing them with a single right bracket `]`;
4. repeating step #3 until MS Word returns **"All done. We made 0 replacements."**;

### Images

**<sub>Default Format</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>Replace All `^f` with `[^&]`</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>`^f` surrounded by `[]`</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>New footnote added</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>Replace All `^f` with `[^&]`</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>`^f` surrounded by `[]` and `[[]]`</sub>**
[image]

Comment: Another thing, replacing `^f` with `[^&]` doesn't affect the footnote itself, it works only for the main one in the page, not the one below.

Comment: I updated [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1777201/) after some additional tests.  I describe two use cases that will create the "Find and Replace" behavior you are seeing.  I expect the behavior to be consistent between Word 2010 and Word 365.  Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Here is a link of the demo doc file, all I need is a command to automatically make the number at the bottom links to its adjacent number in the main document above: https://www.hipdf.com/download-file?share_id=NT0m7QBrIEMlIgOmjV7wIg

Comment: Mike, I looked at your file and you did more to it than what you described.  For my part, **1.** I installed Word 2010, **2** I copied and pasted your text into a new document, **3.** I added a footnote and copied your footnote text to it. **4.** I did a find/replace **`[^&]`** for **`^f`**  worked exactly as I described in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1777201/) .  The format `[]` format works and bi-directional linking continues to work too.  **Here is the sample file:** https://www.file.io/vhPN/download/7RACHC4RP3J0

Comment: You said you added a footnote, I don't want to add, I wanted to fix the bi-directional linking in an already-made file., which I send an example from.  I know creating footnotes works, I am talking about that exact same file.  Anyway, I've upvoted you answer, and thanks for your time.